# Scale dash pattern with line width

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I would like to have dash patterns which scale proportionally to the active line width like shown in the following example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\newdimen\gpdashlength
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}
\gpdashlength=0.5\pgflinewidth
\tikzset{gp path/.style={dash pattern=on 7.5\gpdashlength off 7.5\gpdashlength}}

\draw[gp path] (1.012,3.528)--(11.947,5.469);

\pgfsetlinewidth{4pt}
\gpdashlength=0.5\pgflinewidth
\draw[gp path] (1.012,2.557)--(11.947,6.440);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This works fine, but I would like to set some property of `gp path` once, so that it always selects the current line width scaled by some factor. I tried using `gp path/.code`, but that has no effect. The following document doesn't show anything:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\newdimen\gpdashlength
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{gp path/.code={\gpdashlength=0.5\pgflinewidth},
         gp path/.style={dash pattern=on 7.5\gpdashlength off 7.5\gpdashlength}}

\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}
\draw[gp path] (1.012,3.528)--(11.947,5.469);

\pgfsetlinewidth{4pt}
\draw[gp path] (1.012,2.557)--(11.947,6.440);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It seems to me like the `.code` part is executed after the `.style` so that `\gpdashlength` isn't set properly.

Whats wrong with the second example?

Note that this is supposed to be used for gnuplot's `lua tikz` terminal, so an overall restructuring of the example may not be possible. That means, that the `\pgflinewidth` cannot be contained in the dash pattern definition, since this is located in a system-wide style file, and the scaling factor between the line width and the dash pattern can be changed from document to document.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `\gpdashlength` is a length, not a macro, and then it is not expanded, but replaced by a length value. So, if you want to change that value, an assignment has to be made before the length is evaluated, and you cannot do it inside `.code` key because, as you guessed, it is not executed before evaluating the style.

A solution is to change `\gpdashlength` from a lengt to a macro, i.e:

```
\def\gpdashlength{0.5*\pgflinewidth}
```

This way, when this macro is found as part of the dash pattern, it is expanded, so the current value of `\pgflinewidth` is used at that point. You have to change the dash pattern to include the multiplication sign (`*`) before `\gpdashlength`. I.e:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\def\gpdashlength{0.5*\pgflinewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
         gp path/.style={dash pattern=on 7.5*\gpdashlength
                                     off 7.5*\gpdashlength}}

\draw[thin, gp path] (1.012,3.528)--(11.947,5.469);
\draw[very thick, gp path] (1.012,2.557)--(11.947,6.440);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: Result]

Note that this works because tikz parses the mathematical expression containing `*`. That is, after all expansions are performed, tikz "sees" the following dash pattern (assuming that, for example, `\pgflinewidth` is `0.8pt` in this example):

```
 dash pattern=on 7.5*0.5*0.8pt off 7.5*0.5*0.8pt
```

Tikz parser is able to evaluate that product. Otherwise this won't work. You cannot generally change a length register by a macro as I did here.

Comment: Oh yes, that does indeed do the trick! Thank you.